# How to move a marker in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I'd like to move automaticaly a marker to x kilometers.

Here is my code:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var myMap = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: myMap,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("show_map"), myOptions);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            flat: false,
            map: map
        });

    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: x kilometers from where?  In what direction? What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. x kilometers randomly from the original position of the marker.

Comment: @Beno, could you please explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? When the map is loaded do you want to move a marker from position A to position B, or do you want to just animate it?

Comment: I just want to move a marker from position A to position B without animation. It's for a real estate website and I don't want to show the real position of the properties. Thank you Martin.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmetsalu/2nEuP/)?

Comment: That's it, this function suits. But how can I do to calulate automaticaly the new coords corresponding to a point situated 2 kilometers for example from the original point? (I'm sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.
Instead of using reverse geocoding from the address, I get the coordinates in a DB and apply them shift like this:

```
var coordinates_str, actual_lat, actual_lng, adjusted_lat, adjusted_lng;

actual_lat = adjusted_lat = '<?php echo $lat ?>';
actual_lng = adjusted_lng = '<?php echo $lng ?>';

adjusted_lat = parseFloat(actual_lat) + (Math.random() -.5) / 25;
adjusted_lng = parseFloat(actual_lng) + (Math.random() -.5) / 25;
coordinates_str = String(adjusted_lat) + String(adjusted_lng);

var coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(adjusted_lat, adjusted_lng);

var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(adjusted_lat, adjusted_lng);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Simply move your marker with:

```
function moveMarker( map, marker ) {

    marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( Lat, Lng) );
    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( Lat, Lng) );

};
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I calculate the new coords automaticaly from the original location which is obtained using geocoder: 

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the Marker after it is aggregated:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        flat: false,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
```

Miss one parameter "draggable" and set to TRUE, by default is FALSE.

Comment: Thanks Wises, but I want the marker to be moved automaticaly before it is placed on the map